# Surjectivity of derivative of a vector valued function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ be a function such that $f(x,y,z)=f(x+y,0,x+z)$ for all $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3$. I want to prove that $f^{'}(x)$ can never be onto for all point $x\in \mathbb R^3$ of the type $(a,0,c)$.

Here if $f$ is a $C^{1}$ function, then by using inverse mapping theorem the problem may be solved. But unfortunately it is not given. Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: $f$ is a linear map, and so it is its own derivative at every point, i.e. for all $x$, $f'(x) \equiv f$. As $f$ is not surjective, neither can $f'(x)$ be.

Comment: How is $f$ a linear map? @xyzzyz

Comment: $f$ statisfies $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ and $f(ax) = af(x)$.

Comment: Are you sure it's $f(x+y,0, x+z)$? The problem would make more sense if it was $f(x+y,0,y+z)$.

Comment: You seem to be using $x$ as a vector in R^3 and also as a real number. Not good. Restate the problem please.

Comment: It is given that $f(x,y,z)=(x+y,0,x+z)$ and not $f(x,y,z)=(x+y,0,x+z)$. How can we show that $f$ is linear?@ xyzzyz

Comment: The problem is taken from Analysis in Vector spaces by Mustafa Ackoglu et al. 5.50 (page no. 217)

Comment: Do you see the problem of using $x$ in two different ways, one for a vector and for a real number?

Comment: Are we assuming $Df(p)$ exists everywhere?

Comment: @WilliamChang: An affine map is not a linear map. You example doesn't satisfy neither $f(u + v) = f(u) + f(v)$, nor $f(au) = af(u)$. Don't forget this: "linear maps" $\subsetneq$ "affine maps".

Comment: @AlexM. You're right--my bad. But still, how is every linear map its own derivative? For instance, if we just consider the identity $f:{\mathbb R} \to {\mathbb R}$ given by $x \mapsto x$, how is that its own derivative? $f'(x)=1.$

Comment: @WilliamChang: For $f(x) = ax : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, one identifies the number $a$ with the map $x \to ax$, the last one being linear. Alternatively, you may think of identifying the number $a$ with the $1 \times 1$ matrix $(a)$. Things get clearer when you move to vector functions of several variables, where the derivative at a point can be represented as a matrix filled with the partial derivatives of the components of the function at that point (see my answer below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $f = f\circ T,$ where $T$ is the linear map $(x,y,z) \to (x+y,0,x+z).$ If we asssume $Df(p)$ exists for all $p,$ then by the chain rule

$$Df(p) = Df(T(p))\circ DT(p) = Df(T(p))\circ T,$$

where we have used the fact that $DT(p) = T$ (true for any linear map). Now the range of $T$ is contained in the two dimensional subspace $ \mathbb R \times \{0\} \times \mathbb R,$ so the rank of $T$ is $\le 2$ (it's actually $2,$ but never mind). Thus the rank of $Df(T(p))\circ T$ is at most $2,$ hence it is not surjective.

Like @Alex M., I do not understand the $(a,0,c)$ business.

Answer (score 1):

Since you reference $f'$, $f$ must be differentiable. The inverse function theorem can actually be relaxed from $C^1$ functions to differentiable functions (see [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/the-inverse-function-theorem-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps/)), so the argument you had in mind still applies.

Comment: This question is asked before inverse function theorem is stated. So, I think one should solve it without the help of inverse function theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $f'(x,y,z) : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ is a linear map; to say that it is surjective means, in this case, to say that $\text{rank } f'(x,y,z) = 3$, which is equivalent here to saying that $\det f'(x,y,z) \ne 0$. Letting $f = (u,v,w)$, let us compute this determinant.

Begin by computing the partial derivatives of the given relationship:

$$\begin{align}
\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} (x,y,z) = & \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} (x+y, 0 ,x+z) + \frac {\partial f} {\partial z} (x+y, 0, x+z) \\
\frac {\partial f} {\partial y} (x, y, z) = & \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} (x+y, 0, x+z) \\
\frac {\partial f} {\partial z} (x, y, z) = & \frac {\partial f} {\partial z} (x+y, 0, x+z)
\end{align}$$

and replace the second and third pieces of relationship into the first one, to obtain

$$\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} (x,y,z) = \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} (x, y, z) + \frac {\partial f} {\partial z} (x, y, z) ,$$

and this is valid at evry point of $\Bbb R^3$, not just at points of the form $(a,0,c)$!

Writing the components of $f$ explicitly and dropping the argument $(x,y,z)$, the above means that

$$\begin{align}
\frac {\partial u} {\partial x} = & \frac {\partial u} {\partial y} + \frac {\partial u} {\partial z} \\
\frac {\partial v} {\partial x} = & \frac {\partial v} {\partial y} + \frac {\partial v} {\partial z} \\
\frac {\partial w} {\partial x} = & \frac {\partial w} {\partial y} + \frac {\partial w} {\partial z}
\end{align}$$

(again, this is valid everywhere).

From this it follows that

$$\det f'(x,y,z) = \begin{vmatrix}
\frac {\partial u} {\partial x} & \frac {\partial u} {\partial y} & \frac {\partial u} {\partial z} \\
\frac {\partial v} {\partial x} & \frac {\partial v} {\partial y} & \frac {\partial v} {\partial z} \\
\frac {\partial w} {\partial x} & \frac {\partial w} {\partial y} & \frac {\partial w} {\partial z}
\end{vmatrix} (x,y,z)
= \begin{vmatrix}
\frac {\partial u} {\partial y} + \frac {\partial u} {\partial z} & \frac {\partial u} {\partial y} & \frac {\partial u} {\partial z} \\
\frac {\partial v} {\partial y} + \frac {\partial v} {\partial z} & \frac {\partial v} {\partial y} & \frac {\partial v} {\partial z} \\
\frac {\partial w} {\partial y} + \frac {\partial w} {\partial z} & \frac {\partial w} {\partial y} & \frac {\partial w} {\partial z}
\end{vmatrix} (x,y,z) = 0$$

because the first column is a linear combination of the other two. Since the determinant is $0$, it follows that $\text{rank } f'(x,y,z) \le 2$, so $f'(x,y,z)$ is not surjective for *any* $(x,y,z) \in  \Bbb R^3$ (not just for the points of the form $(a,0,c)$!).

(In my opinion, this is a very poor exercise because it suggests the student that the points $(a,0,c)$ are in some way special and that the statement of the problem holds only for them, which is clearly not the case. I bet there are better course materials available.)

Answer (score 1):

I really like **zhw.**'s answer but let me show another approach.

For a fixed $(x,y,z)$ define a function
$$
h(t) = f(x+t, y-t, z-t), \quad  t \in \mathbb R.
$$
Obviously, $h(t) = f(x+y,0,x+z)$, so it's constant and if a derivative of $f$ exists at $(x,y,z)$, we have
$$
0 = h'(0) = f'(x,y,z) (1,-1,-1).
$$
Thus $f'(x,y,z)$ is not surjective.

We don't even need the existence of a Frechet derivative. If a linear Gateaux derivative at $(x,y,z)$ exists than it can't be surjective either.

Comment: That's a nice solution because we only need to assume $f'$ exists for that one $(x,y,z).$ I'm not sure I understand your last sentence.

Comment: A [Frechet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) is just the usual derivative. A [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) is something less. It can exist at a point even if a function is not differentiable there in the usual (i.e. Frechet) sense. When we calculate $h'(0)$ as a limit, we approach the point $(x,y,z)$ staying on a straight line - so we get exactly a directional derivative in the direction $(1,-1,1)$.

Comment: Right, I know that. But you wrote "a directional derivative is enough". Enough for what? (I upvoted your answer btw)

Comment: @zhw. Thanks. Sorry for bad wording. I meant a (linear) Gateux derivative. It's enough to state the problem (of surjectivity of a linear mapping) and prove it.